# How to initialize data table in R shiny to show user which columns are editable

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have a data table in R shiny which I have made editable using the DT package editor package. My problem now is I would like to initialize the table so that user can clearly see which columns they can edit. My current table initializes like this:

[image]

I would like the data table to initially look like this:

[image]

My first thought was to adjust the value of input$table_cell_clicked when the app is launched to the value it should be when activated. I couldn't figure out how to do this.

My next idea was to simulate a click event using JavaScript. I was able to simulate the click event (shown in example code) but I'm not sure how to access specific elements within the table. Also, I feel there may be a better way to do it than simulating a bunch of click events on the table. Here's my code:

```
#devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT@feature/editor')
#install.packages("shinythemes")
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinythemes)
library(V8)


jscode <- '$(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function(){$("#clickMe").trigger("click");},100);
});'

ui <- fluidPage(tags$script(jscode)
                ,actionButton("clickMe", "Click Me")
                ,dataTableOutput("table")

                )

server <- function(input, output,session) {


  Data<-data.frame(x1=1:10,x2=1:10,x3=11:20)
  values <- reactiveValues(dfWorking = Data) 

    observeEvent(input$clickMe,{
      values$dfWorking<-data.frame(x1=11:20,x2=11:20,x3=31:40)
    })
    observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
      info = input$table_cell_edit
      i = info$row
      j = info$col+1
      v = info$value
      values$dfWorking[i, j] <<- DT:::coerceValue(v, values$dfWorking[i, j])
    })

    output$table <- renderDataTable({values$dfWorking}
                                    ,escape=FALSE,server=FALSE,selection='single',rownames=FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```